# Visual Studio Python Projects do not conform to latest syntax

Tags: python, visual-studio

I looked up this error and found an SO article from 7 years ago: TypeError: **repr** returned non-string (type NoneType)

I have VS 2019 Python projects installed, using Python 3.9.  When I run this code I can use a print statement to prove dunder repr override is being called and returning something.  But no matter what I try, the return statement appears to not be working.  I still get the non-string returned even when I'm obviously returning "Hello"

I'm installing PyCharm and am going to learn that IDE because I get no replies from Microsoft.

BTW -- the syntax of using , *, in a signature and then having only keyword (named) args after it also breaks in Python Projects.

Here is my code:

```
class Position:
    def __init__(self, latitude, longitude):
        if not (-90 <= latitude <= +90):
            raise ValueError("Latitude {} is out of range.", latitude)
        if not (-180 <= longitude <= +180):
            raise ValueError("Longitude {} is out of range.", longitude)
    
        self._latitude = latitude
        self._longitude = longitude
    
    @property
    def latitude(self):
        return  self._latitude
    
    @property
    def longitude(self):
        return  self._longitude
    
    def __repr__(self):
        print("Position latitude: " + str(self.latitude) + " and longtitude: " + str(self.longitude))
        return "Hello" #str("Position latitude: " + str(self.latitude) + " and longtitude: " + str(self.longitude))
```

Here is the error I keep getting:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: **repr** returned non-string (type NoneType)

Here is what we should see:

[image]

Thanks for any help.

-- Mike

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run code other than what you have here. What's the trace of the error?

Comment: Can't reproduce this error.

Comment: I have put in the code I'm running in VS 2019.  Using a Python Project, Python Environment set in the project as 3.9

I'm not sure what is creating the error code.  If I use a print statement and concatenate strings correctly this works.

Here's the odd thing -- creating 2 new classes in the global scope the return statement work, take that with a pound of salt. :)  I suspect in the next part of the lesson code a fat finger was eliminated.  Let me prove or disprove it with both versions of the code.

If it's me, I'll answer my own question :) albeit regrettably, LOL.